# python regex replace all occurances of word that starts with ":" and next character is letter

Tags: python, regex

I have a sql select (sel = "sql select text")  in which variables are defined as :var_name

```
select  ... from (
select  ... from ( 
select  ... from  table1
where session_started between  toDateTime(:DatumOd) and toDateTime(:DatumDo)
and session_id in (select distinct ...  from table2
    where   session_start>=toDateTime('2019-01-01 10:11:12') and session_module=:channel
            and session_start between  toDateTime(:DatumOd) and toDateTime(:DatumDo)
            and ( domain_name in (:domain) or 'All domains' in (:domain) )
            and (technology in (:technology) or 'All' in (:technology))
            and (CASE when session_principal_role='Self care' then agent_name else session_principal_role end in  (:application) 
            or 'All' in (:application) )  )
order by session_id desc , execution_id desc, step_started desc, step_id desc)
) where step_type=:step_type and ...
```

Variables start with ":" and ends with parenthesis or white space.
I have to replace every :var_name with ${var_name}.

At the moment I am using:
re.sub(r":(\w+)", r"${\1}", sel) which gives:

```
select  ... from (
select  ... from ( 
select  ... from  table1
where session_started between  toDateTime(${DatumOd}) and toDateTime(${DatumDo})
and session_id in (select distinct ...  from table2
    where   session_start>=toDateTime('2019-01-01 10${11}${12}') and session_module=${channel}
            and session_start between  toDateTime(${DatumOd}) and toDateTime(${DatumDo})
            and ( domain_name in (${domain}) or 'All domains' in (${domain}) )
            and (technology in (${technology}) or 'All' in (${technology}))
            and (CASE when session_principal_role='Self care' then agent_name else session_principal_role end in  (${application}) 
            or 'All' in (${application}) )  )
order by session_id desc , execution_id desc, step_started desc, step_id desc)
) where step_type=${step_type} and ...
```

Everything works well except 2019-01-01 10:11:12 date constant. As there is ":" character in it, the rest is recognized as variable name.

I should replace only if after ":" character next character is letter.

How to do that?

Comment: Instead of `\w` try `[A-Z][a-z]`

Comment: Probably, `r'\B:([^\W\d_]\w*)'` will do. `\w` matches letters, digits, underscores and more in Python 3.x. `[^\W\d_]` matches any Unicode letter. `re.sub(r'\B:([^\W\d_]\w*)', r'${\1}', sel)`

Comment: I posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54863967/3832970) with the implementation of your requirements below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex, which uses a positive look ahead to ensure it only selects the variable that are followed by either space or `)`

```
:(\w+)(?=[ )\n]|$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J9L76F/2)**

Check out this Python code,

```
import re

s = '''select  ... from (
select  ... from ( 
select  ... from  table1
where session_started between  toDateTime(:DatumOd) and toDateTime(:DatumDo)
and session_id in (select distinct ...  from table2
    where   session_start>=toDateTime('2019-01-01 10:11:12') and session_module=:channel
            and session_start between  toDateTime(:DatumOd) and toDateTime(:DatumDo)
            and ( domain_name in (:domain) or 'All domains' in (:domain) )
            and (technology in (:technology) or 'All' in (:technology))
            and (CASE when session_principal_role='Self care' then agent_name else session_principal_role end in  (:application) 
            or 'All' in (:application) )  )
order by session_id desc , execution_id desc, step_started desc, step_id desc)
) where step_type=:step_type and ...:DatumOd
:DatumOd'''

print(re.sub(r':(\w+)(?=[ )\n]|$)', r'${\1}',s))
```

Prints only your intended variables ignoring colon in date,

```
select  ... from (
select  ... from (
select  ... from  table1
where session_started between  toDateTime(${DatumOd}) and toDateTime(${DatumDo})
and session_id in (select distinct ...  from table2
    where   session_start>=toDateTime('2019-01-01 10:11:12') and session_module=${channel}
            and session_start between  toDateTime(${DatumOd}) and toDateTime(${DatumDo})
            and ( domain_name in (${domain}) or 'All domains' in (${domain}) )
            and (technology in (${technology}) or 'All' in (${technology}))
            and (CASE when session_principal_role='Self care' then agent_name else session_principal_role end in  (${application})
            or 'All' in (${application}) )  )
order by session_id desc , execution_id desc, step_started desc, step_id desc)
) where step_type=${step_type} and ...${DatumOd}
${DatumOd}
```

Comment: Your solution is better, but it doesn't work if after variable name is line break. Try to put last "and ..." in new line and you will see that :step_type will stay not converted.

Comment: :(\w+)(?=[ )\n]) will solve this problem, but how to be sure that I am paying attention to all possible end characters?

Comment: @user3225309: Ok, in case the line ends with your variable name, you can use this regex `:(\w+)(?=[ )\n]|$)` which expects either a space or `)` or end of line. Let me update my post.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following pattern: `'\W:(\w+)'` in order to select *something* following a colon only if the colon does not follow a *word* character. It works with that example, but I am unsure whether it is enough for the general requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements, you may use

```
s = re.sub(r'\B:([^\W\d_]\w*)', r'${\1}', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jECgyV/1).

**Details**

- `\B:` - a `:` that is not preceded with a word char (or is at the string start)
- `([^\W\d_]\w*)` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern):

  - `[^\W\d_]` - any *letter*
  - `\w*` - any 0+ letters, digits, underscores.

NOTE: If you want to match ASCII only letters and digits, and you are using Python 3.x, use `re.A` or `re.ASCII` flag:

```
s = re.sub(r'\B:([^\W\d_]\w*)', r'${\1}', s, flags=re.A)
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/g94PEA):

```
import re
s = "select  ... from (\r\nselect  ... from ( \r\nselect  ... from  table1\r\nwhere session_started between  toDateTime(:DatumOd) and toDateTime(:DatumDo)\r\nand session_id in (select distinct ...  from table2\r\n    where   session_start>=toDateTime('2019-01-01 10:11:12') and session_module=:channel\r\n            and session_start between  toDateTime(:DatumOd) and toDateTime(:DatumDo)\r\n            and ( domain_name in (:domain) or 'All domains' in (:domain) )\r\n            and (technology in (:technology) or 'All' in (:technology))\r\n            and (CASE when session_principal_role='Self care' then agent_name else session_principal_role end in  (:application) \r\n            or 'All' in (:application) )  )\r\norder by session_id desc , execution_id desc, step_started desc, step_id desc)\r\n) where step_type=:step_type and ..."
s = re.sub(r'\B:([^\W\d_]\w*)', r'${\1}', s, flags=re.A)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
select  ... from (
select  ... from ( 
select  ... from  table1
where session_started between  toDateTime(${DatumOd}) and toDateTime(${DatumDo})
and session_id in (select distinct ...  from table2
    where   session_start>=toDateTime('2019-01-01 10:11:12') and session_module=${channel}
            and session_start between  toDateTime(${DatumOd}) and toDateTime(${DatumDo})
            and ( domain_name in (${domain}) or 'All domains' in (${domain}) )
            and (technology in (${technology}) or 'All' in (${technology}))
            and (CASE when session_principal_role='Self care' then agent_name else session_principal_role end in  (${application}) 
            or 'All' in (${application}) )  )
order by session_id desc , execution_id desc, step_started desc, step_id desc)
) where step_type=${step_type} and ...
```